# Automapper , Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping error

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

**Movie**

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string MovieName { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }


        public int MovieTypeId { get; set; }
        public MovieType MovieType { get; set; }

        public int DirectorId { get; set; }
        public Director Director { get; set; }

        public ICollection<MovieActor> MovieActors { get; set; }
      

        public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;
```

**MovieCreateModel**

```
  CreateMap<MovieCreateModel, Movie>()
                    .ForMember(src => src.MovieName, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.MovieName))
                    .ForMember(src => src.Price, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Price))
                    .ForMember(src => src.Year, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Year))
                    .ForMember(src => src.MovieTypeId, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.MovieTypeId))
                    .ForMember(src => src.DirectorId, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.DirectorId))
                    .ForMember(src => src.MovieActors, opt => opt.Ignore());

var map = _mapper.Map<Movie>(CreateModel);
```

I am trying map MovieCreateModel to Movie but ı am getting this error :

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

**Debug Screen**

[Create Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1S5Q.jpg)

Where is my fault ? Thanks.

```
public class MovieCreateCommand
    {
        private readonly IMovieStoreDbContext _context;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public MovieCreateModel CreateModel { get; set; }

        public MovieCreateCommand(IMovieStoreDbContext context, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _context = context;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        public void Handle()
        {
            Movie movie = new Movie
            {
                DirectorId = CreateModel.DirectorId,
                IsActive = true,
                MovieName = CreateModel.MovieName,
                MovieTypeId = CreateModel.MovieTypeId,
                Price = CreateModel.Price,
                Year = CreateModel.Year,
                MovieActors = new List<MovieActor>()
            };

            // var movie = _mapper.Map<Movie>(CreateModel);

            foreach (var actorId in CreateModel.MovieActorsId)
            {
                var actorResult = _context.Actors.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == actorId);
                var directorResult = _context.Directors.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == CreateModel.DirectorId);

                if (actorResult is not null && directorResult is not null)
                {
                    movie.MovieActors.Add(new MovieActor { Actors = actorResult, Movie = movie });
                }
                else if (actorResult is null)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Aktör bulunamadı.");
                }
                else if (directorResult is null)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Yönetmen bulunamadı.");
                }
            }
            _context.Movies.Add(movie);
            _context.SaveChanges();

        }
        

        public class MovieCreateModel
        {
            public string MovieName { get; set; }
            public decimal Price { get; set; }
            public int Year { get; set; }

            public int MovieTypeId { get; set; }

            public int DirectorId { get; set; }

            public ICollection<int> MovieActorsId { get; set; }

        }
}
```

I found my mistake, MovieActor List is null so This causes the error. I resolved problem without automapper.

Can ı create List object while mapping with Authomapper?

Comment: can you post the exact structure of `Movie` and `MovieCreateModel`. It seems you only posted the former

Comment: You either map explicitly, or you use AM, it doesn't really make sense to do both at the same time. It defeats AM's very purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative approach which doesn't require third party dependencies ;)

```
public static Movie ToMovie(this MovieCreateModel model)
{
    return new Movie 
    {
        Name = model.MovieName,
        Price = model.Price,
        Year = model.Year,
        DirectorId = model.DirectoryId,
        TypeId = model.MovieTypeId
    };
}

// Usage
var entity = newMovieModel.ToMovie();
```

Notice that this approach don't have mapping limitations ;)